# Is it a good idea to implement a sklearn model for a real time image processing application?

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn, tensorflow

I'm testing a support vector machine (SVM) model trained with scikit learn library for image processing, but i don't know exactly if for real time this library could be better than tensorflow or both are equal according to the parameters fitted to the model.

Comment: Are you training a model and then using that model to make real-time classifications of new images?

Comment: Yes, what i'm trying to do is a real time classification.